# Migrating testcafe suite to TypeScript

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We have a huge testcafe e2e tests database and as a part of TS migration I'm rewriting test helper files to TypeScript.

But when I import a .ts helper inside of a .js test, test run fails with a syntax error not recognizing TypeScript syntax.

What am I doing wrong and what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Such a scenario is not meant to work and it's not described in TestCafe's documentation.
It looks like the incompatibility of the `import` statement from the `js` file (processed by the Babel preprocessor internally) and the `import` statement from the `ts` file (processed by the TypeScript compiler internally).
Try to set the `allowJs` option of the TypeScript compiler using TestCafe's [--compiler-options](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html#compileroptions) setting.

Comment: tried that, but nothing has changed. anyway, I think I'll wait with this feature until testcafe allows for configuring babel/ts